# Is an empty textbox considered an empty string or null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, null

The text box in question is involved in an if statement within my code, something to the effect of

```c#
if (textbox.text != "") 
{
    do this
}
```

I am curious if an empty text box will be considered an empty string or a null statement.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try to use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, this will make sure of validating the whitespace too without having to trim it.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text))
{
    //code here
}
```

According to documentation `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` evaluates to:

```
return String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0;
```

[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx):

> Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.

Answer (score 4):

In short it will be an empty string, but you could use the debugger and check that yourself.

However for best practice use `IsNullOrEmpty` or `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text)) {

}
```

Alternatively:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text)) {

}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It will be an empty string but better to check with this [IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) or [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx)

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.text))
{
  //do this
}
```

*IsNullOrWhiteSpace* is also take care of whitespace in input string. So if you don't want to execute the code for whitespace too then use second option.

Answer (score 2):

It will be considered an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

```
string search = txtSearch.Text.Trim() != "" ? txtSearch.Text.Trim() : "0";
```

Answer (score -4):

if (textbox.text != "" || textbox.text != null)

Comment: Please add some brief text to answer the question being asked. Also, look closely at your code - the `if` condition is always true.