# Check Whether a TextBox is empty or not

Tags: c#, wpf, string, validation, user-input

I have a TextBox. And I want to check if it's empty.

Which way is better

```
if(TextBox.Text.Length == 0)
```

or

```
if(TextBox.Text == '')
```

?

Comment: `if(TextBox.Text == "")` is better because Text might be null.

Comment: You could do `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty text box to be considered an empty string or null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16612057/empty-text-box-to-be-considered-an-empty-string-or-null)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if TextBox is empty and return MessageBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156458/check-if-textbox-is-empty-and-return-messagebox)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You should use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure it is neither empty nor null (somehow):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    // Do something...
}
```

More examples [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/isnullorempty).

For practical purposes you might also consider using `String.IsNullOrWhitespace()` since a TextBox expecting whitespace as input probably negates any purpose, except in case of, say, letting the user pick a custom separator for stuff.

Answer (score 8):

I think

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text)
```

or

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox.Text)
```

are your best options.

Comment: I think `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` is probably better because it fits most people's idea of what "empty" means.

Comment: I agree, it's not often that a couple of spaces is an expected input from a user.

Comment: Been using IsNullOrEmpty on my humble c# shop app and was a fatal decision as now I have supplier names with different types of white spaces by the lazyness of my workers, the IsNullOrWhiteSpace solved everything.

Answer (score 2):

If one is in XAML, one can check whether there is text in a `TextBox` by using  `IsEmpty` off of `Text` property.

Turns out that it bubbles down to `CollectionView.IsEmpty` (not on the string property) to provide the answer. This example of a textbox watermark, where two textboxes are displayed (on the editing one and one with the watermark text). Where the style on the second Textbox (watermark one) will bind to the `Text` on the main textbox and turn on/off accordingly.

```
<TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tEnterTextTextBox, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="False" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=tEnterTextTextBox, Path=Text.IsEmpty}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tEnterTextTextBox, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tEnterTextTextBox, Path=Text.IsEmpty}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

---

- [CollectionView.IsEmpty explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25700024/285795)
- [Help Text WaterMark to Disappear when user Types in (answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26846846/285795) (this is the full example which I used from the partial answer given above).

Answer (score 1):

You can put that code in the `ButtonClick` event or any event:

```
//Array for all or some of the TextBox on the Form
TextBox[] textBox = { txtFName, txtLName, txtBalance };

//foreach loop for check TextBox is empty
foreach (TextBox txt in textBox)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The TextBox is empty!");
        break;
    }
}
return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
    if(textBox1.TextLength == 0)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("The texbox is empty!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way

```
If(txtTextBox1.Text ==“”)
{
MessageBox.Show("The TextBox is empty!");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Farhan answer is the best and I would like to add that if you need to fullfil both conditions adding the OR operator works, like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text.Text))
{
  //Code
}
```

Note that there is a difference between using `string` and `String`

Comment: -1: This is unnecessary. `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` checks everything that `string.IsNullOrEmpty` checks. From MSDN: "String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace: Indicates whether a specified string is null, empty, or consists only of white-space characters.". Also, since string is an alias for System.String, there's no difference between them unless they decide to change the implementation of String in a way that impacts this. Edit: It's generally encouraged to use the aliases, but that doesn't mean there's a difference.

Comment: It's different trust me! I used this code when I replied, Null or white doesn't throw exception when you add a non printable such as NCHAR(0x00A0) thus you need Null or empty

Comment: Yes, it's different, since one checks for whitespace and the other does not. But if you don't want to permit whitespace, using just `string.isNullOrWhiteSpace` for the validation is enough, since it also checks for null or empty. Also, I tried both functions with '\u00A0' (non-breaking space) and neither "threw an exception". So I fail to see your point. Could you explain further?

Comment: if the user adds any non printable character by copy and paste the white character will avoid null or white and enter the database

Comment: In the case of \u00A0, during my test, it is correctly recognized as a whitespace character in `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. Do you have any example for other non-printable characters that won't be recognized as whitespace?

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion the easiest way to check if a textbox is empty + if there are only letters:

```
public bool isEmpty()
    {
        bool checkString = txtBox.Text.Any(char.IsDigit);

        if (txtBox.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (checkString == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: The OP was only asking about an empty textbox. This answer adds an extra layer of logic that was not asked about. Also, there are a few bugs in the code from what I can tell. If the textbox is empty then the IsEmpty function returns false. If the textbox contains only '1' then IsEmpty returns true.