# How to mark TextBox as empty?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

When there is no text entered in any of TextBoxes, I want a new form to open with a message in it

```
if (rectangleBox.Checked == true && (int.Parse(side_a.Text) > 0 && 
    int.Parse(side_b.Text) > 0))
    {
      var drawRectangle = new Rectangles(70 + int.Parse(side_a.Text), 
      80 + int.Parse(side_b.Text),
      50 + int.Parse(side_a.Text), 70 + int.Parse(side_b.Text));
      Figures.Add(drawRectangle);
    };  

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(side_a.Text) &&
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(side_b.Text) &&
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(side_c.Text))
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        Form1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

But I get an error on the following lines

```
    if (rectangleBox.Checked == true && (int.Parse(side_a.Text) > 0 && 
        int.Parse(side_b.Text) > 0))
```

"System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check Whether a TextBox is empty or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298857/check-whether-a-textbox-is-empty-or-not) The exact duplicate

Comment: What do you mean by 'mark as empty' ??

Comment: @Taw When there is no text in TextBoxes

Comment: Folks are trying to help you but you make it really hard! What do you mean by 'mark' ??? Also: 'no text' or no valid numbers'? also data missing in one or all boxes? - General rule until you can't express your goal clearly you can't write code for it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netcore-3.1) or [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netcore-3.1) function to check if the `TextBox` is empty.

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Or IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Comment: @JonasH You are correct.

Comment: How does that answer the question? He asked not about testing but marking..

Comment: @TAW Why the answer does not answer the question? What do you understand the question is?

Comment: As I wrote above I do not understand the question. Maybe you guessed right, though..

Comment: @JeremyRock Now I get an error when I try IsNullOrWhiteSpace or IsNullOrEmpty
Add it above

Comment: Which error do you get??

Comment: @ДимитърУзунов You are probably failing on int.Parse. Can you post the string values of side_a, side_b, side_c?